# RenameColumn during db migration in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I noticed strange thing with db migration that I couldn't fix.

Please help.

I have a class

```
public class Subscription : BaseEntity
{
    ...
    [Index("IX_Subscription_Status", IsUnique = false)]
    public int? Status { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I renamed property `Status` to `BeforeStatus` and ran `Add-Migration` command in Visual Studio.

It generates:

```
DropIndex(...IX_Subscription_Status...);
DropColumn(... Status ...);
AddColumn(... BeforeStatus ...);
CreateIndex(...IX_Subscription_BeforeStatus...);
```

I didn't want to drop column, so I changed migration script to

```
DropIndex(...IX_Subscription_Status...);
RenameColumn(...,Status,BeforeStatus)
CreateIndex(...IX_Subscription_BeforeStatus...);
```

and ran `Update-Database` migration. It passed without errors and changed the database.

I added a new property `AfterStatus` to the class

```
[Index("IX_Subscription_AfterStatus", IsUnique = false)]
public int? AfterStatus { get; set; }
```

and ran `Add-Migration` command. It generates:

```
AddColumn(... AfterStatus  ...);
CreateIndex(...IX_Subscription_AfterStatus...);
```

I ran `Update-Database` migration and it passed without errors and changed the database.

So from my point of view, everything is correct and db corresponds c# code. I checked `__MigrationHistory` table, it contains all latest migrations.

BUT, when I run code, it fails with a `DbContext` error:

> The model backing the 'MyContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

If I run `Add-Migration` command again, it generates:

```
DropIndex(...IX_Subscription_Status...);
DropColumn(... Status ...);
AddColumn(... BeforeStatus...);
CreateIndex(...IX_Subscription_BeforeStatus...);
AddColumn(... AfterStatus...);
CreateIndex(...IX_Subscription_AfterStatus...);
```

Why? Why does it generate migration script? Is this error related to `RenameColumn` operation? Maybe it is because of manually changes of migration script?

Please, does anybody know how to make Entity Framework understand that I have already updated the database?

Comment: Could you also include the configuration for the Status column? Either the complete definition of the entity with the attribute-based configuration, or the EF fluent configuration (or both, if relevant)

Comment: Can you add the Context exception?

Comment: I updated code to show Status configuration and exception description

Comment: If you generate an update script (update-database -Script) you might be able to visually inspect that code and see if the context keys match, etc. Otherwise the workaround is to just force EF to recognize the changes by doing `add-migration MyColumnChange -IgnoreChanges` This will change the internal model used to do the schema compare.

Comment: Steve, to inspect update script (-Script) is cool idea, i will try it, thank you.